# Retrieve JSON column data from MySQL using go

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from a column using MySQL and go and sqlx. I have the below JSON structure in a MySQL table column named data.

```
[{"name": "Abc", "ids": [108, 33, 34, 35]}]
```

I do the following to retrieve the data

```golang
sqlstr := `SELECT field1, field2, data FROM myTable`

records := []DataStruct{}

    var err = *new(error)
    err = store.DB().Select(&records, sqlstr)
    
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, entry := range records {
        mainResponse := MainResponse{}
        mainResponse = MainResponse {
            Field1: entry.Field1,
            Field2: entry.Field2,
            Data: entry.Data,
        }
```

My structures are as below

```golang
type MainResponse struct {
    Data                []Data          `db:"data"`
    Field1              string          `db:"field1"`
    Field2              string          `db:"field2"`
}

type DataStruct struct {
    Data                []Data          `db:"data"`
    Field1              string          `db:"field1"`
    Field2              string          `db:"field2"`
}

type Data struct {
    Name                store.NullString          `db:"name"`
    Ids                 []int                     `db:"ids"`
}
```

I get the below error in err variable when the select query runs

```
sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "data": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]test.Data
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: `Data` is my JSON struct for the data column. use `[]byte` where?

Comment: Whoops, ah ok, you need to change `records := []DataStruct{}` to `records := []Data{}`. Or you could use `records := DataStruct{}` and `store.DB().Select(&records.Data, sqlstr)`

Comment: actually `DataStruct` has more fields which I have not added above in my question so my sql query also has those other fields. `Data` is one of the JSON field along with other fields so cannot use `records := []Data{}`

Comment: If you have a json field in your sql table you likely need to change your data strcture to be `type DataStruct struct {Data []byte `db:"data"`}` and then unmarshal the bytes to json using json.UnMarshal as a second step.

Comment: could you please show that using some code? Maybe add an answer considering I have other string fields in the same query.

Comment: Yes, I will add code, can you add the mysql definition? Or at least the parts of it you can show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253846/discussion-between-girish-and-maxm).

Comment: @maxm I got it working. Changed the datatype of the column to store.NullString and unmarshalled to json after extracting it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.4#Scanner) interface.

```golang
type DataStruct struct {
    Data   DataList `db:"data"`
    Field1 string   `db:"field1"`
    Field2 string   `db:"field2"`
}

type DataList []Data

func (ls *DataList) Scan(src any) error {
    var raw []byte
    switch src := src.(data) {
    case string:
        raw = []byte(src)
    case []byte:
        raw = src
    default:
        return nil // or return an error, e.g. fmt.Errorf("type %T not supported by Scan", src)
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(raw, ls)

    // NOTE: keep in mind that the unmarshal may fail
    // depending on how store.NullString is implemented
    // and the corresponding JSON value.
}
```